# Python syntax for MATLAB/Octave colon operator a:dx:b

Tags: matlab, discretization, octave, numpy

I am trying to rewrite some MATLAB/Octave code in Python, and I don't know what would be the nicest or most intuitive way of writing

```
octave:10> dt = 0.1;
octave:12> T = 0:dt:1
T =

    0.00000    0.10000    0.20000    0.30000    0.40000    0.50000    0.60000    0.70000    0.80000    0.90000    1.00000
octave:15> dt = 0.17;
octave:16> T = 0:dt:1
T =

    0.00000    0.17000    0.34000    0.51000    0.68000    0.85000
```

which creates a discretization of the interval [0, 1] with step 0.1, as it's seen. I referred to the NumPy/MATLAB mathesaurus and it uses `arange` function, but it's not suitable for non-integer values as it's stated in [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and shown in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10011302/554319). On the other hand, playing with `linspace` is not appealing to me because it takes care of endpoints, not spacing.

Which would be a straight-forward, one-line way of doing this in Python?

Comment: Relevant document: http://www.mathworks.es/support/solutions/en/data/1-4FLI96/index.html?solution=1-4FLI96 it's published on April's Fools though... :P

Comment: Previous link exists no more, here goes Google cache copy http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jO5BiOfv5TEJ:www.mathworks.in/support/solutions/en/data/1-4FLI96/index.html%3Fsolution%3D1-4FLI96+http://www.mathworks.es/support/solutions/en/data/1-4FLI96/index.html%3Fsolution%3D1-4FLI96&cd=9&hl=it&ct=clnk&gl=it

Comment: Also typing in MATLAB `doc colon` and `help colon` gives further insight. This is a tricky matter, as already noted by Walking Randomly http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=789

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATLAB and Octave are susceptible to the same subtle floating-point issues that Python is, where you can get a slightly unexpected result if you do not anticipate rounding issues.  On the other hand, this is quite convenient syntax to have!  You can easily "bake" a simple function to do this from the existing functionality in `numpy.linspace`, which is a very Pythonic way to do things!

```
# use Python3 syntax in Python2 to get clean, consistent integer division  
from __future__ import division   
import numpy as np

def lrange(r1, inc, r2):
    """Provide spacing as an input and receive samples back by wrapping `numpy.linspace`"""
    n = ((r2-r1)+2*np.spacing(r2-r1))//inc
    return np.linspace(r1,r1+inc*n,n+1)

> lrange(0,0.1,1)
array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ])

> lrange(0,0.17,1)
array([ 0.  ,  0.17,  0.34,  0.51,  0.68,  0.85])
```

**Edit**: I've added a floating point epsilon to the computation that will handle small floating-point errors in the operands/representation per [Juanlu001's comment](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2336/python-syntax-for-matlab-octave-adxb/2340#comment4457_2340).

Comment: Ah, didn't know about the existence of the integer division operator! In fact you do not need the `__future__` import statement. Thank you!

Comment: You're absolutely right, an earlier version of the function used "true division".  I'm going to leave the import statement in there because it's a reasonably important piece of the language to know about, even if it's not used here.  There are [more details on division in Python in PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).

Comment: Well, after some days I went back to this and discovered that `lrange(0, 0.1, 1)` is actually `[0., ..., 0.8, 0.9]`. This is because 0.1 is actually 0.100000000000000006. Here and there is mentioned that there are roundoff errors and the like, but then I don't know how it is implemented in MATLAB / Octave.

Comment: --I mean, at least in my computer.

Comment: @Juanlu001 - That's annoying, I think the only fix would be to do something like: ((r2-r1)+np.spacing(r2-r1))//inc

Comment: MATLAB is subject to these odd round off issues as well. That's why I always try to represent steps like this by scaling *integer* ranges whenever possible.